# How to get and set the sum of the values of an array object with infinite depth of this array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I need to convert an array of objects into a new array with objects including a new type field
`percent`. The task is this - each object in the array has a `defaultWeight` field with a numeric value. In this array, I have to add the `defaultWeight` of the current array to the sum of `sumArray`, then I take the `defaultWeight` value, divide by `sumArray` and multiply by 100 `(defaultWeight / sumArray * 100)`. Thus, I get the percentage of the number that I have to put in the new `percent` field, which depth of these arrays would not be encountered in the future. Help me, I've been racking my head for the second day. Below is an example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Блок «Тест1»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.3,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Планирование активностей",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Выполнение плана по визитам",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Выполнение плана по групповым мероприятиям",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Выполнение маркетинговой стратегии (включает три KPI)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Охват базы",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Соблюдение кратности посещения специалистов",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Интервальность",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Охват базы",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Соблюдение кратности посещения специалистов",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Интервальность",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Время, проведённое на визитах в день",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Средняя длительность визита",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Доля рабочего дня на активности",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Геолокация",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Блок «Тест2»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.2,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "% выполнения «Двойной визит» (оценка РМа)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "% выполнения «Аудит» (оценка РМа)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "% выполнения «Двойной визит» (оценка Аудитора)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "% выполнения «Аудит» (оценка Аудитора)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Средневзвешенное с весами оценки РМа и Аудитора",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Блок «Тест3»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.5,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 26,
                "name": "Выполнение плана продаж",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.9,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "Темп прироста",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "name": "Evolution Index",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 29,
                "name": "Динамика фактической доли на рынке",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "name": "Сравнение фактической доли на рынке с долей по РФ",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Should turn into:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Блок «SoReX»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.3,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Планирование активностей",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Выполнение плана по визитам",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Выполнение плана по групповым мероприятиям",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Выполнение маркетинговой стратегии (включает три KPI)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Охват базы",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "percent": 33.33,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Соблюдение кратности посещения специалистов",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "percent": 33.33,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Интервальность",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "percent": 33.33,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Время, проведённое на визитах в день",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Средняя длительность визита",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Доля рабочего дня на активности",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Геолокация",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 12.5
            }
        ],
        "percent": 30
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Блок «Качество»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.2,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "% выполнения «Двойной визит» (оценка РМа)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "% выполнения «Аудит» (оценка РМа)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "% выполнения «Двойной визит» (оценка Аудитора)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "% выполнения «Аудит» (оценка Аудитора)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Средневзвешенное с весами оценки РМа и Аудитора",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 20
            }
        ],
        "percent": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Блок «Рынок»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.5,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 26,
                "name": "Выполнение плана продаж",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.9,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 90
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "Темп прироста",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 2.5
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "name": "Evolution Index",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 2.5
            },
            {
                "id": 29,
                "name": "Динамика фактической доли на рынке",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 2.5
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "name": "Сравнение фактической доли на рынке с долей по РФ",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": [],
                "percent": 2.5
            }
        ],
        "percent": 50
    }
]
```

I tried to solve this problem by recursion, but my knowledge of algorithms, unfortunately, leaves much to be desired

```
public setSum(weight: any, id?: number) {

const calculation = (weights) => weights.map(block => {
  return {
    ...block,
    percent: block.defaultWeight / this.sumBlock * 100
  };
});

if (weight.length !== []) {
  this.sumBlock = weight.reduce((acc, block) => {
    return acc += block.defaultWeight;
  }, 0);

  if (id) {
    this.cloneBlocks = this.cloneBlocks.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          groups: weight.map(block => {
            return {
              ...block,
              percent: block.defaultWeight / this.sumBlock * 100
            };
          })
        };
      } else {
        return { ...item };
      }
    });
    return;
  } else {
    this.cloneBlocks = weight.map(block => {
      return {
        ...block,
        percent: block.defaultWeight / this.sumBlock * 100
      };
    });
  }
}

weight.forEach(block => {
  if (block.groups) {
    this.setSum(block.groups, block.id);
  }
});

console.log(this.cloneBlocks);
```

}

Comment: We need to see the relevant code, as well as your failed attempts.

Comment: @M0nst3R готово

Comment: @Thomas Zimmermann has a good answer below, but please keep in mind the comment I have under it.

Comment: Your input has a duplicate key that will overwrite itself. ("children" with ids 5, 6 and 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should do the job, see comments for details on how it works:

```js
// Start of Dataset
const object = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Блок «Тест1»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.3,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Планирование активностей",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Выполнение плана по визитам",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Выполнение плана по групповым мероприятиям",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Выполнение маркетинговой стратегии (включает три KPI)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Охват базы",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Соблюдение кратности посещения специалистов",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Интервальность",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Охват базы",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Соблюдение кратности посещения специалистов",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Интервальность",
                        "weight": null,
                        "defaultWeight": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Время, проведённое на визитах в день",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Средняя длительность визита",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Доля рабочего дня на активности",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Геолокация",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Блок «Тест2»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.2,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "% выполнения «Двойной визит» (оценка РМа)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "% выполнения «Аудит» (оценка РМа)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "% выполнения «Двойной визит» (оценка Аудитора)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "% выполнения «Аудит» (оценка Аудитора)",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Средневзвешенное с весами оценки РМа и Аудитора",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Блок «Тест3»",
        "weight": null,
        "defaultWeight": 0.5,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 26,
                "name": "Выполнение плана продаж",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.9,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "Темп прироста",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "name": "Evolution Index",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 29,
                "name": "Динамика фактической доли на рынке",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "name": "Сравнение фактической доли на рынке с долей по РФ",
                "weight": null,
                "defaultWeight": 0.025,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
];

// Note: This function will mutate its parameter
function setPercent(dataset) {
  // Sum the total defaultWeight for siblings
  const totalWeight = dataset.reduce((acc, next) => acc + next.defaultWeight, 0);
  dataset.forEach(node => {
    // Set percent of siblings if totalWeight is different from 0
    if (totalWeight !== 0) {
      node.percent = node.defaultWeight / totalWeight * 100;
    }
    // Recurse for children
    setPercent(node.children);
  });
}

// Run function, but clone object to avoid mutation
const dataset = structuredClone(object);
setPercent(dataset);

console.log(dataset);
```

Comment: _Note:_ Your function mutates the parameter, please indicate that. Also, although not needed, you might want to protect against empty weights and dividing by 0.

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann
Thank you, you saved me from a nervous breakdown in such a short period of time!)